# NetBeans 8.1 IDE Installer won't let me click on Next button (Ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: netbeans

I have downloaded the installer for NetBeans 8.1 IDE.  Already have the JVM, and have granted executable permission on the.sh.  When I open the installer from the terminal, I get the window that says "Welcome to the NetBeans 8.1 IDE Installer", the list of the packages and runtimes included, and a Customize, Next, and Cancel button.  However, it stops there, and will not let me click on any of the buttons.  What is most peculiar is that it will not let me Quit, nor will it let me Force Quit..apparently it is still responding.  Any ideas as to what this issue may be?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .sh file to install netbeans then you may have opened that .sh file in terminal directly.

Try opening it using following command:

```
sudo bash <netbeans_installationfile.sh>;
```

Comment: `sudo` isn't necessary to run NetBeans and thus shouldn't be used.

Comment: I know sudo isn't necessary to run NetBeans. Question is next button is disabled while installation of netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1520743)

I solved by following [this guide](http://java-buddy.blogspot.de/2015/11/install-netbeans-81-0n-ubuntu-1510.html)

Install Oracle 1.8 java and fix the jdk location of your `~/netbeans-8.1/etc/netbeans.conf` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` like this:

`netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"`